# WebEx XML API not returning actual meeting attendee list

Tags: webex

I'm using the WebEx XML api to "get meeting attendees".

> get meeting attendees
>
> https://developer.cisco.com/site/webex-developer/develop-test/xml-api/xml-api-reference/

1. When I call `https://siteName.webex.com/WebExUtils.XMLURL` the response only includes the attendees which were invited by mail even, including those that did not actually attend the meeting. The response does not include attendees which did attend the meeting by click the meeting url.

*How can I get the attendees attending my meeting by clicking the meeting url?*

2. As you know,the `meetingKey` is changeless and static to a specific user.but a user is able to host not only one meeting in a while. Could I get a specific meeting attendees? Whether should I change to another API?

Comment: this is the xml API.

Comment: I am also looking for the same as when user attend meeting by Join URL this APi is not providing value of those attendees.. Also from history attendee API's are providing list of attendees but it takes approx 24 hrs to update attendee list.

Answer (score 0):

Actual attendee list should be available with the History Service API

[LstmeetingattendeeHistory](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/webex-xml-api-reference-guide/#!lstmeetingattendeehistory)

> Allows meeting hosts or site administrators to request detailed attendee
> information for any meeting session previously hosted on the site.